# How to best pass information between view models in Xamarin forms - Prism

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

I'm just not sure which method to use. I want to pass data between view models. I'm using Xamarin forms Prism. I can use the Navigationparameters but I feel like there's a better way of passing data without having to worry about keys. Does anyone suggest a Singleton? or is there's any other method that perhaps I haven't thought about?

Comment: Are we talking about passing information to view models you're navigating to or in a general sense? You'll have the three options as always: static (evil), built-in service (eventaggregator) or custom service (singleton), plus navigation parameters (if you're navigating). All work well and have their advantages and disadvantages...

Comment: What I dislike about the Navigation parameters is the fact you need to keep track of the keys

Comment: I totally agree, `RequestNavigate<ParameterType>` would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the NavigationParameteres for Prism, rather than a singleton.

NavigationParameteres were built exactly for this purpose and function like a dictionary.